I have a 2016 Mazda BT50
I just installed a pair of aftermarket LED headlights from Big Red. While installing them I made sure not to touch any of the important parts and just handle the main part. After installation I turn on my car, flick the lights on manually and they work, all is good. But then 10 seconds later my right then left headlights turn off. I could still put them on high beam and they will stay on. But they will only turn off when the engine is running and on low beam. I checked the wiring and all and they look great, I have no idea what happening.

(1) Is the base of the LED unit getting very warm or actually hot? (2) If you want to self-diagnose this, you must measure your voltage on the battery terminal clamps, not the battery posts while the engine is running. If you don't have a digital multimeter, you can buy one for under $20 at a store that sells cheap import tools, or get one online. Please report voltage and comment about how hot the base is getting.
